# First click doesn't register?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

For some reason, from time to time, I'll have this issue where the first time I click something, nothing will happen. But, the second time I click the exact same spot, it will work as normal. This usually lasts about a day, then it goes away. It can return in a day, or in this case, after a 3-month hiatus. It is extremely annoying having to double-click everything (or tripple-click where a double-click is required). What might be causing this? It seems like the same issue described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/trackpad-and-mouse-require-two-taps-clicks-to-register-first-click), but I don't have jiTouch or BetterTouchTool. It is not resolved with a reboot, or even an SMC reset.

Macbook5,2 (2009)

Comment: This might seem like a silly idea, but what if some windowless application keeps putting itself in front? Then the first click would be required just to get the app you are trying to interact with to the front. This hypothesis should be easy to confirm or disprove by paying careful attention to the menubar or the coloured buttons in the top left of your window. When the window is not active, the buttons should be grey.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I don't think that's it, as I clicked "add comment", the window frame and buttons were the normal color, and it required two clicks.

Comment: Right. It was a long shot, but worth a try. If this were happening to me, I would consider a full reinstall, after making triply sure I have plenty of backups of course. This looks to me like the sort of problem that requires detailed knowledge of the relevant drivers for its solution, and that sort of knowledge is probably rare outside of Cupertino.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an option for me. See http://pastebin.com/vsv2ggGz

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen disregard first comment, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it was caused by Spotify. It may have something to do with the ads that refresh every 10 seconds, but it started happening immediately after I opened it a minute ago, the 3-month hiatus ended the day I reinstalled it, and it usually happens in about hour-long increments, about how long I usually have Spotify open. I'm now 100% sure of this, it directly correlates with when the app is open or closed. It's strange, though, the window I'm in doesn't appear to lose focus, and this even happens when clicking on something in Spotify, but Spotify is what's causing it beyond a doubt.